# Не пойму передачу аргументов в функцию

Tags: javascript

Каким образом передаются аргументы из `sum(1, 2)` в декоратор?

```
// вспомогательная функция для проверки на число
function checkNumber(value) {
  return typeof value == 'number';
}

// декоратор, проверяющий типы для f
// второй аргумент checks - массив с функциями для проверки
function typeCheck(f, checks) {
  return function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (!checks[i](arguments[i])) {
        alert( "Некорректный тип аргумента номер " + i );
        return;
      }
    }
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

// обернём декоратор для проверки
sum = typeCheck(sum, [checkNumber, checkNumber]); // оба аргумента - числа

// пользуемся функцией как обычно
alert( sum(1, 2) ); // 3, все хорошо
```

Comment: В массиве `checks[]` хранятся ссылки на функции. Под каким-то индексом хранится ссылка на `sum()`.

Comment: @Arhad нет, её там нет. В `checks` попадает `[checkNumber, checkNumber]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему переменные не передаются в декоратор. Декоратор возвращает(подсовывает) нам свою функцию, вместо оригинальной.

```
  return function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      if (!checks[i](arguments[i])) {
        alert( "Некорректный тип аргумента номер " + i );
        return;
      }
    }
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

Этот код выполняет наша функция со своими переменными и в конце вызывается уже оригинал. Ну и так как код получается, как бы выполняется в самой функции, то ему доступны параметры функции через объект `arguments`.

Хотя тут главное понять принцип, как написать этот декоратор и что к параметрам функции можно обращаться через `arguments`.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения!